# How to release or hide UIImageView in iOS? hidden is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

My purpose is when I drag an object, a small `UIImageView` shows, when the touch is ended, the `UIImageView` is released.

```
- (IBAction)TLMove:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {

//add UIImage view to show the scaled dot
UIImageView *scaleUPView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 30, 100, 100)] ;
scaleUPView.layer.zPosition = 300 ;
[scaleUPView setImage:self.OriginImage] ;
[self.view addSubview:scaleUPView] ;

self.TopLeftPoint.center = [sender locationInView:self.TopLeftPoint.superview] ;

targetTL = self.TopLeftPoint.center  ;

if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded || sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled || sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed)
{
    [scaleUPView setHidden:YES] ; // not working still shows
    [scaleUPView removeFromSuperview] ; //not working still shows
}
}
```

But this is not working at all, I tried `scaleUPView.hidden =YES`, still not working. The `scaleUPView` will always show, I want it to deallocated in ARC mode, I can't release it when enabling reference counting.

Comment: Are you sure it is comming in if statement

Comment: yes, I added a printf in the if, and statements inside if runs.

Answer (score 2):

u can set `alpha = 0`. and u must check that ure inside if statments.

so ure code might be like this:

```
if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded || sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled || sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed)
{
    NSLog(@"inside if statement"); \\ 
    [scaleUPView setAlpha:0] ; 
    [scaleUPView removeFromSuperview] ; 
}
```

Hope this helps .

Comment: Thanks, I tried this. Now I just figured it out, I must put the scaledUPView definition in the viewController class (interface) declaration part. then everything works fine .

Answer (score 0):

You should call `[self.view addSubview:scaleUPView];` inside this if statement:

`if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)`

or you would add `scaleUPView` to `self.view` many times when `sender.state` changed.